# Best Way to Populate Form Fields From Select Field

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask

I am serving a flask app and trying to use jquery to populate form fields based on information in a dropdown menu.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    cats = [{'name': 'fluffy', 'size': 'big'}, {'name': 'smelly', 'size': 'small'}]
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', cats=cats)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return "thanks"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="/" method="post">
      <select>
        {% for cat in cats %}
          <option size={{ cat['size'] }}>{{ cat['name'] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="size" value="">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</html>
```

What I am looking for is a script to put into index.html that watches cat select and populates size input with the size value in the option.

I should note that this input should stay editable, so I can override the size input after the selection has been made. Bonus points if the script only populates the size input if it does not already contain a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python (added cat without a known size)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    cats = [{'name': 'fluffy', 'size': 'big'},
            {'name': 'smelly', 'size': 'small'}, 
            {'name': 'Mr Meow', 'size': None}]
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('test.html', cats=cats)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return "thanks"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="" action="/" method="post">
    <select onChange="changeSizeInput()" id="catSelect">
    {% for cat in cats %}
      <option size={{ cat['size'] }}>{{ cat['name'] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
    <input type="text" name="size" id="catSize">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

<script>
  function changeSizeInput() {
    var cat = document.getElementById('catSelect')
    var size = cat.options[cat.selectedIndex].getAttribute("size");
    if (size == 'None') {
      size = ''
    }
    document.getElementById('catSize').value = size;
  }
  changeSizeInput()
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</html>
```

So the trick is to have a event listener in your select menu, which is executed when your cat is changed. Afterwards, it will look up the size of the selected cat, and then update the input with the size of the selected cat. If the size is `None`, it sets the size to an empty string. The function is also executed when loading the page, so it will also load the first cat in the select box.

It's a bit ugly, because a python `None` is not really conferted to a javascript `null`, but it will do the job.

For jquery, change the code to:

```
function changeSizeInput() {
  var size = $('#catSelect option:selected').attr('size')
  if (size == 'None') {
    size = ''
  }
  $('#catSize').val(size);
}
changeSizeInput()
```